# AIR application talking to Java

Tags: java, air, remoting, invocation

I have situation when I need to communicate with Java process somehow. Java handling all DB works AIR just UI. It would be very nice to have AFM protocol implementation over sockets. Ideally approach with RemoteObject already existing in framework but working over other medium that HTTP wiuld be the best! Does anybody knows if such thing exists? Tank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [merapi](http://merapiproject.net/)

Comment: Just edited my question. I read about Merapi, their approach is a bit convoluted and they are in very early stage of development I expect lots of glitches along the road.

Comment: I guess because there is no any other alternatives your suggestion qualified to be the best :)

Comment: There should be better ways to do that, but I don't know them :( Joa Ebert has some great slides from his recent talk at the FITC conference: http://www.slideshare.net/joae/the-apparat . He compiles Java to actionscript bytecode, so I'm pretty sure he would know how to deal with this. He is well above most actionscript developers.

Comment: Thank you George, Looks like I quite modified MERAPI already to adopt it to my needs. I emulate exact behavior of RemoteObject.

Comment: @voipsecuritydigest.com Might a bit late, but the Native Process API in AIR 2.0 seems to allow some alternatives (e.g. http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/12/embedding-tomcat-and-blazeds-in-an-air-2-0-application/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using BlazeDS
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/

You can use RemoteObject to call remote methods implemented in java.  Works great.

Comment: In my scenario there is no application server, as I mentioned there is no HTTP. So I wont be able to use BlazeDS.